# Using an array of promises, each with metadata and Promise.All() to resolve

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

In my application, I build an array of calls to a 3rd party API that each returns  a promise and then use `Promise.All` to act on the results once they all resolve.

I find myself repeating a pattern where I use this approach but also need to store additional metadata for each entry. If it's an array of file loader promises for example, I might want to store the file type, intended destination etc. for each.

Currently, I build another array with this information and since I know the results from `Promise.All` will appear in the same order they were added, I can get the find both the result of the API call and the metadata using an appropriate index.

I wondered if was possible instead to create an array of containing both the API calls that returns a promise and the data as a single JavaScript object so

---

that both can easily be extracted after they resolve.

Despite lots of trying, I wasn't able to find a syntax that worked for me but it feels like it's possible.

Can anyone help?

```js
function loadStuff(value, delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), delay));
}

async function loadStuffandEnhance(value, delay) {
  let result = await loadStuff(value, delay);

  result += '__enhanced';

  return result;
}

function test() {
  let loader_promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    loader_promises.push(
      loadStuffandEnhance(`item${i}`, Math.random() * 1000 + 100),
    );
  }

  Promise.all(loader_promises).then((loaded_things) => {
    loaded_things.forEach(function (each) {
      console.log('resolving', each);
    });
  });
}

test();
```

I *think* this is my question distilled down to a trivial example.  Instead of calling a loader and using the result once it resolves, I just return the filename after a short timeout.

Comment: Instead of your promise resolving to `apiResponse` you make it resolve to `{apiResponse, metaData}`

Comment: James: That's what I had at one point but the return in the JS console was confusing - the data member was there but the result of the API call was inside (IIRC) a <Promise> block with no obvious ay to get to the actual value.

Comment: Should be fine!  If you have trouble with a specific piece of code please provide that code (in textual form) by adding it to your question.

Comment: @MollyBirk Well if you were only going to act on the results once they arrive, you don't need to get the actual values until you have awaited them via `Promise.all`? Please post the code you're currently using in an [edit] so we can give a concrete answer.

Comment: @Bergi I posted a snippet

Comment: @MollyBirk Where's the metadata in that snippet? What's the part you are having trouble with?

Comment: I tried making loadStuff async, using await to wait for it to complete and then mixing in my data into what was "loaded" (the API provides a data user data field you can add to) and then returning that - it did what I needed but it seemed like that was no longer asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi I couldn't make it work so I haven't included it but I as thinking of something like :     loader_promises.push( {
        loadStuff(`item${i}`, Math.random() * 1000 + 100),
        data: "foo" }
      )

Comment: "*it seemed like that was no longer asynchronous*" - why? It sounds like that should have worked, but you'll need to show us the code of your attempt.

Comment: "*I as thinking of something like `loader_promises.push( { loadStuff(…), data: "foo" } )`*" - yeah, that won't work, since now your pushing plain objects into the `loader_promises` array, and `Promise.all` only works with an array of promises.

Comment: @Bergi I'm having trouble reproducing what I wrote and I'm not having much luck explaining it in a way that's useful.. I'll keep trying and update my post when I figure it out.

Comment: Ok - I think I represented my changes in the new snippet.  It does indeed seem to do the right thing (and I think represent my use case) - is this a good approach or is there a better way ?

Comment: Yes, `loadStuffandEnhance` looks like a totally fine approach

Comment: @Bergi - thank you so much for the insightful discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Writing a custom function, that could return the Array of promises for each API call and any aggregated info.

Something similar to below could work.

```
async function fetchAPIsAndCompileResults() {
      // API endpoints
      const apiEndpoint1 = 'https://example.com/api/endpoint1';
      const apiEndpoint2 = 'https://example.com/api/endpoint2';
    
      // Function to fetch data from an API
      async function fetchData(apiUrl) {
          const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
          return await response.json();
      }
    
      // Execute both API calls concurrently and keep them as promises
      const apiCallPromises = [
        fetchData(apiEndpoint1),
        fetchData(apiEndpoint2),
  ];

  // Aggregate your specific information, from each API call into an array
  // Wait for all API call promises to resolve
  let aggregatedInfo = [];
  const results =  (await Promise.all(apiCallPromises)).forEach(result => {     // Grab your aggregated info
    if (result && result.items) {
      aggregatedInfo = [...aggregatedInfo, ...result.items];
    }
  });

  // Finally return an object containing both the promises and the aggregatedInfo
  return {
    apiCalls: apiCallPromises, // Array of promises for each API call
    aggregatedInfo // The aggregated information from all API calls once they resolve
  };
}

// Example usage
fetchAPIsAndCompileResults().then(({ apiCalls, aggregatedInfo }) => {
  Promise.all(apiCalls).then(() => {
    console.log('API Calls Completed');
    console.log(aggregatedInfo); // Aggregated information after API calls have resolved
  });
});
```